# Are Spring Annotations supposed to work on @Bean defined classes in @configuration?

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations

So reading on the `@Lookup` documentation it says it wont work on factory methods in the `@configuration` classes, and I've read that spring annotations wont be processed whenever we use the new instantiation.
So I tried, and the `@autowired` annotations work on `@Bean` defined instances:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("autowired_qualifier_resource")
public class Application {

    @Bean(name="firstBean")
    @Qualifier("qualifierBean")
    TestBeanInterface myBean(){
        return new TestBean1();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
        System.out.println(context.getBean("firstBean"));

    }
}



    public class TestBean1 implements TestBeanInterface {
    private BeanInterface bean;

    @Autowired
    public TestBean1(){

        System.out.println("TestBean1");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setBean( BeanInterface bean){
        System.out.println("SetBean :" + bean);
        this.bean = bean;
    }

}
```

The `setBean` method is called and gives the error of having more than one object for same type.
So why doesn't the lookup method work on `@Bean` defined classes when other annotations do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Lookup.html)

> Such lookup methods can have default (stub) implementations that will
>   simply get replaced by the container, or they can be declared as
>   abstract - for the container to fill them in at runtime. In both
>   cases, the container will generate runtime subclasses of the method's
>   containing class via CGLIB, which is why such lookup methods can only
>   work on beans that the container instantiates through regular
>   constructors: i.e. **lookup methods cannot get replaced on beans
>   returned from factory methods where we cannot dynamically provide a
>   subclass for them**.

I hope that is self explanatory.

Comment: What about other annotations on beans returned from factory methods?

Comment: Each annotation serves different purpose. You may ask your question to a wider audience to get a good answer.